# Algorithm to fit galaxies

Tags: galaxy, gravitational-lensing, algorithm, fits

Do you know of any other data analysis algorithm that fits 2-D analytic functions to galaxies and point sources directly to digital images, other than [GALFIT](https://users.obs.carnegiescience.edu/peng/work/galfit/galfit.html)? Especially to subtract lens light from strong lensing images?

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE! Did I guess the link to the package correctly?

Comment: @B--rian Yes thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two most general, publicly available packages for galaxy image fitting (other than GALFIT) are probably
[Imfit](https://github.com/perwin/imfit) and
[ProFit](https://github.com/ICRAR/ProFit). (Note that I am the developer of Imfit.)

There is also [Lenstronomy](https://github.com/sibirrer/lenstronomy), which is specialized for fitting gravitational lenses; this might be more relevant to your particular needs, though I know very little about it.